# how can i let my salary_level switch case become a valid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sorting, error-handling

```
select concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as name,J.job_title, salary, J.min_salary, J.max_salary,(case 
when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.9) then 'SS' 
when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.7) then 'S' 
when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.5) then 'A' 
when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.3) then 'B' 
when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.1) then 'C'
else 'D' end) as salary_level, salary_score = case salary_level
when 'SS' then 1
when 'S' then 2
when 'A' then 3
when 'B' then 4
when 'C' then 5
when 'D' then 6 end from employees E inner join jobs J  on E.job_id = J.job_id order by  salary_score
```

the system show the invalid column name 'salary_level' at the case method "salary_score = case salary_level ... "

Comment: Please don't post images.  Text is desired.

Comment: You cannot reference a computed column in the same select clause.  Repeat the code that computed the column or make it a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can not point reference to a column generated in the query. You can re use the same CASE statement for generating 1 to 6 as below-

```
select concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as name,J.job_title, salary, J.min_salary, J.max_salary,
(case 
    when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.9) then 'SS' 
    when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.7) then 'S' 
    when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.5) then 'A' 
    when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.3) then 'B' 
    when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.1) then 'C'
    else 'D' 
end) as salary_level, 
salary_score = (case 
    when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.9) then 1 
    when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.7) then 2 
    when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.5) then 3 
    when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.3) then 4 
    when salary >= (J.min_salary + (J.max_salary - J.min_salary)*0.1) then 5
    else 6 
end) 
from employees E inner join jobs J  on E.job_id = J.job_id order by  salary_score
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the alias name will not be available in the same `select` statement. You need a `sub-select` or `apply` operator to use the alias name.

I prefer `Apply` operator in cases like this, this avoids `sub-select` and looks clean

```
SELECT Concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS NAME, 
       j.job_title, 
       salary, 
       j.min_salary, 
       j.max_salary, 
       cs.salary_level, 
       salary_score = CASE salary_level 
                        WHEN 'SS' THEN 1 
                        WHEN 'S' THEN 2 
                        WHEN 'A' THEN 3 
                        WHEN 'B' THEN 4 
                        WHEN 'C' THEN 5 
                        WHEN 'D' THEN 6 
                      END 
FROM   employees E 
       INNER JOIN jobs J 
               ON e.job_id = j.job_id 
       CROSS apply (SELECT CASE WHEN salary >= ( j.min_salary + ( j.max_salary - j.min_salary ) * 0.9 ) THEN 'SS' 
                             WHEN salary >= ( j.min_salary + ( j.max_salary - j.min_salary ) * 0.7 ) THEN 'S' 
                             WHEN salary >= ( j.min_salary + ( j.max_salary - j.min_salary ) * 0.5 ) THEN 'A' 
                             WHEN salary >= ( j.min_salary + ( j.max_salary - j.min_salary ) * 0.3 ) THEN 'B' 
                             WHEN salary >= ( j.min_salary + ( j.max_salary - j.min_salary ) * 0.1 ) THEN 'C' 
                             ELSE 'D' 
                           END) cs (salary_level) 
ORDER  BY salary_score
```